# Excel 2016 - Application.visible=true - Generates new instances of excel

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a userform that hides the application. However, when I close the userform and set application,visible = true, the application becomes visible, but 2 new instances of excel are created that cannot be closed, other than by killing the task. On older versions of excel, this code works perfectly.

Hope someone can help. :)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim rs As Worksheet
Dim rngWA As Range


    Set rs = Worksheets("VenDetail")
    Set rngWA = rs.Range("B2:B" & rs.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 2)

    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 1
        .ColumnWidths = "300"
        .RowSource = "VenDetail!" & rngWA.Address
    End With

    Application.Visible = False

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Application.Visible = True
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Making Excel visible or invisible shouldn't generate new Excel instances. Perhaps, we don't see something?

Comment: Exactly. It is not supposed to, but yet it does. Those instances are blank with no workbook, visible or invisible.

Comment: I did find though, if I create a new workbook in one of those instances and then exit the app, the instance is closed. Very strange behavior though.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your entire workbook (without, of course, sensitive data).

Comment: I can do that. How can I send you the file? (Zipped of cause)

Comment: And by the way... Thanks a lot for your help and assistance, Johny. :-)

Comment: Send to excel-macros@ya.ru :)